# How to concatenate this string in php

Tags: php, concatenation

I am trying to add the variable `$link` to the end of this custom query. I have followed this from the official php page http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php but nothing seems to work.

```
<?php

ob_start();
the_category();
$link = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$custom_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1&category_name='. $link);
if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
  while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $all_tags[] = $tag->term_id;
      }
    }
  endwhile;
endif;

$tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags);
$tags_str = implode(",", $tags_arr);

$args = array(
'smallest'  => 12,
'largest'   => 12,
'unit'      => 'px',
'number'    => 0,
'format'    => 'list',
'include'   => $tags_str
);
wp_tag_cloud($args);
?>
```

I have checked the see the variable contains the correct output, which it does. I have also tried typing the category name in the query and this works.

So my question is how do I add the variable to the query?

**EDIT**

If I can print the $link output to a piece of text then I think this will work.

Comment: The out of $link is not added to the string.

Comment: sorry, I didn't saw `ob_start();` I deleted my answer :)

Comment: What happens if you output $link yourself or don't capture the output e.g.? And doesn't WP have another function like `get_the_category()` which would simplify all this?

Comment: get_the_category() doesn't seem to work. Something to do with output being the wrong string or something.